# XSLT test expression to check how many levels deep the URL is

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following URLs, how do I determine how many levels deep the path is?

```
https://example.com/{product}/
https://example.com/(product}/{vendor}
https://example.com/{product}/{vendor}/{location}
```

These are variable strings: `product`, `vendor`, `location`

I have this code that I use for paths with constant values:

```
<xsl:variable name="itemURL">
  <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
</xsl:variable>

<td>
  <xsl:if test="contains($itemURL, '/Section/')">
    <xsl:attribute  name="class">section</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="contains($itemURL, '/Category/')">
    <xsl:attribute  name="class">category</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="contains($itemURL, '/Product/')">
    <xsl:attribute  name="class">product</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>-->
  <a href="{$itemURL}">
    <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
  </a>
</td>
```

CSS for those simple constants:

```
.section {
    font-weight: 600;    
}

.category {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.product {
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

What I want to do is indent or add a bullet or something with css later when the list of URLs go another level deep. Basically I want to nest it so that it's easier for humans to read. Do I have to use regex here or is there a better way that is pure XSLT?

Comment: You could count the `/` characters in the given string.

Comment: This wouldn't work, because the base URL has a trailing `/`.

Comment: @zx485 As long as the URLs are consistent, it can be made to work.

Comment: I could make it so that the URLs have (or don't have) trailing slashes, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <URL>https://example.com</URL>
    <URL>https://example.com/product</URL>
    <URL>https://example.com/product/vendor</URL>
    <URL>https://example.com/product/vendor/location</URL>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="URL">
            <xsl:variable name="path" select="substring-after(., 'https://example.com')" />
            <xsl:variable name="slashes" select="translate($path, translate($path, '/', ''), '')"/>
            <result>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($slashes, '/', '•')"/>  
                <xsl:value-of select="$path"/>  
            </result>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <result/>
  <result>•/product</result>
  <result>••/product/vendor</result>
  <result>•••/product/vendor/location</result>
</results>
```

---

Or:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="URL">
            <xsl:variable name="path" select="substring-after(., 'https://example.com')" />
            <xsl:variable name="count-slashes" select="string-length(translate($path, translate($path, '/', ''), ''))"/>
            <result>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$count-slashes=1">product</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$count-slashes=2">vendor</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$count-slashes=3">location</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>URL</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
            </result>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <result class="URL">https://example.com</result>
  <result class="product">https://example.com/product</result>
  <result class="vendor">https://example.com/product/vendor</result>
  <result class="location">https://example.com/product/vendor/location</result>
</results>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the methods `substring-after` and `translate`.  I'll post what I'll come up with once I've worked out the kinks.

Comment: I did't modify your answer substantially enough to post a new solution, so I'm going to go ahead and accept this solution.